# How to make Squid log cause for TCP connection errors?

Tags: tcp, squid

I've got a bunch of `TCP connection to x.x.x.x/80 failed` in Squid's `cache.log`, but it doesn't say how exactly it failed. Connection time out? Connection reset? No route to host? Some other error? Is there a way to enable more detailed logging to see that?